# How can I change form fields based on dropdown selection with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

In my dropdown I have two options, Yes or No
I want one component to render when user select Yes and other to another component to render if user selects No.
Also I want when page refresh, no options should be shown on page

[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7McB.png)

How can I achieve my goal? I am sharing my code below

```
Here is the dropdown fields, 
const CustomTimings=[
  {label:'Yes', value: 1},
  {label:'No', value: 2}
]

const DateAndTime = () => (
      <div>
        {CustomTimings === 'Yes'
        ? <CustomeTimeYes />
        : <CustomeTimeNo />
    }
return
<div className="input-field">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
              <label htmlFor="customerype">Customer Type</label><br />
              <Select options={CustomerType} onChange={this.handleChangeCT} value={this.state.CustomerType} />
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
              <label htmlFor="learning">Do you have custom timings</label><br/>
              <Select options={CustomTimings} onChange={this.handleChangeCTime} value={this.state.CustomTimings} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><br />
          <div>
          {DateAndTime()}
          <br />
          </div>
```

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong here, either it is showing both components or any one and not changing on refresh

Comment: Can you share your complete code ? where is the value of CustomTimings coming from? It must be stored in a state in order for the component to refresh when you change its value.

Comment: @Saadi updated my question

Comment: I think  {CustomTimings === 'Yes' should be  {this.state.CustomTimings === 'Yes'

Comment: I tried it too, but No

Comment: If you can share your while code for the function, that will help us better understand your code. I asume you are using a class based component right ?

Comment: you have many errors in your code, CustomTimings === 'Yes' is wrong, your object is different

Comment: Minimal working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-leavitt-o8fbh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ChrisG thanks to you bro, your answer is as accurate as I want. God bless you :))

Answer (score 0):

You can work with [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) where you check for a specific condition before render your component.

```
render() {
const { value } = this.state;

return (
   <div>
       {value === 'dropdown' && <Component1>...</Component1>}
       {value === 'text' && <Component2></Component2>}
       {value === 'checkboxes' && <Component3></Component3>}
       ...
   </div>
  )
}
```